# Cannot use org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.jaxws-maven-plugin on JDK8

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, jax-rs

I'm using org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin to generate client stubs for Soap services. Upgrading to JDK8 made this fail with following error:

```
Failed to read schema document 'xxx.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

and something like

```
Failed to read DTD 'XMLSchema.dtd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.
```

Why is this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seems restriction default have changed in JDK8.

Found this: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWSDLExternalSchema

It was however hard for me to find out how to apply this to the Maven plugin, but passing jvm arguments worked:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxws.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <xdebug>true</xdebug>
          <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory>
          <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>foo.wsdl</wsdlFile>
          </wsdlFiles>
          <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</vmArg>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
          </vmArgs>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```