# JAX-WS Maven Plugin Not Working with JDK 8

Tags: java, maven, java-8, jax-ws, maven-plugin

I'm looking for a maven plugin for creating (wsgen) and importing (wsimport) web service into my projects but seems none of them working with JDK 8 so I can not compile my whole project with JDK 8 because of that.

The reason of that is AnnotationProcessorFactory class which has been deleted in JDK 8...

here is the my pom :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.something.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-001-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>some-ejb</artifactId>
<version>0.8-001-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>some-ejb</name>
 ..... Some Dependency
    <build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>gen-local-ws</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ExposedInquiryService</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsgen</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sei>com.behin.inquiry.exposed.ExposedInquiryService</sei>
                                <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <keep>false</keep>
                                <inlineSchemas>true</inlineSchemas>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <resourceDestDir>${wsdl.target-dir}</resourceDestDir>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.5</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
                            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.1</version>
                        </dependency>


                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.17</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is the normal exception:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ project-ejb ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ project-ejb ---
[INFO] Compiling 108 source files to /home/mehdi/Projects/project/ramon-project-app/trunk/project-parent/project-service/project-ejb/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsgen (ExposedprojectService) @ project-ejb ---
[WARNING] '-encoding' is not supported by jaxws-tools:2.2.5
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] project-parent ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.652 s]
[INFO] project-common ..................................... SUCCESS [  2.412 s]
[INFO] project-service .................................... SUCCESS [  0.009 s]
[INFO] project-entities ................................... SUCCESS [  2.268 s]
[INFO] project-ejb ........................................ FAILURE [  2.960 s]
[INFO] project-ear ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project-desktop-app ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project-web-services-local ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.483 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-14T16:21:19+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/508M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsgen (ExposedprojectService) on project project-ejb: Failed to execute wsgen: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :project-ejb

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the exception after mvn clean install -U

```
[WARNING] '-encoding' is not supported by jaxws-tools:2.2.5
[DEBUG] jaxws:wsgen args: [-d, /home/mehdi/Projects/project/ramon-project-app/trunk/project-parent/project-service/project-ejb/target/classes, -verbose, -cp, /home/mehdi/Projects/project/ramon-project-app/trunk/project-parent/project-service/project-ejb/target/classes:/home/mehdi/Projects/project/ramon-project-app/trunk/project-parent/project-service/project-entities/target/project-entities-0.8-001-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/p10pc/afis-entities/0.8-001-SNAPSHOT/afis-entities-0.8-001-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/p10pc/p10pc-afis/0.8-001-SNAPSHOT/p10pc-afis-0.8-001-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/afis/grid/grid.ws/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/grid.ws-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/biometrics/fingerprint-engine/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/fingerprint-engine-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/studio/org.apache.commons.codec/1.6/org.apache.commons.codec-1.6.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.3.2/eclipselink-2.3.2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.0.3/javax.persistence-2.0.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/afis/common-security/0.8-004-SNAPSHOT/common-security-0.8-004-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/web-services-ext/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/web-services-ext-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/common/common-business-objects/0.8-020-SNAPSHOT/common-business-objects-0.8-020-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/afis/biometric-objects/0.8-002-SNAPSHOT/biometric-objects-0.8-002-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/image-capture/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/image-capture-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/com4j/com4j/20110320/com4j-20110320.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/biometrics/fingerprint-graphics-model/0.8-003-SNAPSHOT/fingerprint-graphics-model-0.8-003-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/afis/something-ij/1.49-SNAPSHOT/something-ij-1.49-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/p10pc/p10pc-ws-local/0.8-001-SNAPSHOT/p10pc-ws-local-0.8-001-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/4.0.1/icu4j-4.0.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/persiancalendar/something-persianCalendar/2.1-SNAPSHOT/something-persianCalendar-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/biometrics/biometrics-format/1.5.13-SNAPSHOT/biometrics-format-1.5.13-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-core/0.8.0/servo-core-0.8.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-internal/0.8.0/servo-internal-0.8.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.0/annotations-2.0.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/ramon-common/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/ramon-common-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/afis/civil-web-services-local/0.8-001-SNAPSHOT/civil-web-services-local-0.8-001-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/ramon/upload-common/1.0-SNAPSHOT/upload-common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/iris/iris-engine/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/iris-engine-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/something/integrity/project-iris-web-service-local/1.0-SNAPSHOT/project-iris-web-service-local-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/jaxws-maven-plugin/2.2/jaxws-maven-plugin-2.2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-tools/2.2.5/jaxws-tools-2.2.5.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.5/jaxws-rt-2.2.5.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/xml/ws/jaxws-api/2.2.5/jaxws-api-2.2.5.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.3/jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/xml/soap/saaj-api/1.3.3/saaj-api-1.3.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.annotation/3.1.1-b06/javax.annotation-3.1.1-b06.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/jws/jsr181-api/1.0-MR1/jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.4-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.10/saaj-impl-1.3.10.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/stream/buffer/streambuffer/1.2/streambuffer-1.2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.1.1/woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.1/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/1.4/stax-ex-1.4.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/mimepull/1.6/mimepull-1.6.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/policy/2.2.2/policy-2.2.2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/txw2/txw2/20090102/txw2-20090102.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/2.2.1/istack-commons-runtime-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.3/wstx-asl-3.2.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/gmbal/gmbal-api-only/3.1.0-b001/gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/external/management-api/3.0.0-b012/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.8/ha-api-3.1.8.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.2.4-1/jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.1/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics/0.6.3/jaxb2-basics-0.6.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-runtime/0.6.3/jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.6.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-tools/0.6.3/jaxb2-basics-tools-0.6.3.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.2/commons-lang-2.2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.2.1/maven-project-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.2.1/maven-profile-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.2.1/maven-model-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.2.1/maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.2.1/maven-repository-metadata-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.2.1/maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.2.1/maven-artifact-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9-stable-1/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.2.1/maven-plugin-api-2.2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.jar:/home/mehdi/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/../lib/tools.jar, -wsdl, -inlineSchemas, -r, /home/mehdi/Projects/project/ramon-project-app/trunk/project-parent/project-service/project-ejb/target/generated-sources/wsdl, com.something.project.exposed.ExposedprojectService]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] project-parent ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.305 s]
[INFO] project-common ..................................... SUCCESS [  2.574 s]
[INFO] project-service .................................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] project-entities ................................... SUCCESS [  2.180 s]
[INFO] project-ejb ........................................ FAILURE [  2.509 s]
[INFO] project-ear ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project-desktop-app ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project-web-services-local ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.762 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-14T16:24:12+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/506M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsgen (ExposedprojectService) on project project-ejb: Failed to execute wsgen: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsgen (ExposedprojectService) on project project-ejb: Failed to execute wsgen
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute wsgen
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.execute(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:148)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.MainWsGenMojo.execute(MainWsGenMojo.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen.doMain(WsGen.java:74)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.execute(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:142)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 45 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :project-ejb

Process finished with exit code 1
```

how we can solve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with a dummy WebService class.

It is because you are using an obsolete version of [`jaxws-tools`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-tools) inside your plugin dependencies. You should upgrade to the latest version, which is 2.2.10, instead of 2.2.5.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

As a side-note, you should also consider updating to version 2.3 of [`jaxws-maven-plugin`](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/), which is currently the latest.

Answer (score -1):

Which JAX-WS version are you using is it 2.0 or later ? I read somewhere changes to annotation processing api's and suggest you to upgrade JAX-WS version to 2.10.x to resolve the issue.

Found it - [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117) is the announcement - deprecatged in 1.7 and removed in 1.8.  As suggested upgrade JAX-WS version to fix the issue.

Comment: I used org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons version 2.3.1-b20150201.1248 and org.codehaus.mojo version 2.4.1, none of them worked

Comment: you need maven solution - quick google suggest few workaround as this is already reported  Check https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=241570 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814921/cannot-use-org-jvnet-jax-ws-commons-jaxws-maven-plugin-on-jdk8

Comment: please check the exception, the links you sent are a different story, I get this problem when I want to use wsgen not wsimport. I can not even generate wsdl ...